# how to make an array or list with large numbers in Scala

Tags: scala

I have to create an array or list which contains large numbers ( long ) , but I am unable to create one in an elegant way.
I am currently doing this :

```
val someNums = List(5513831582l,3518715756l,7551150228l,6526827855l,9548153529l)
```

How can i do this in an better way like :

```
val someNums = List(5513831582,3518715756,7551150228,6526827855,9548153529)
```

Comment: How is the second better than the first when it only declares an `Int` instead of `Long`? Also, are these random numbers?

Comment: It could be worse. At least we have the option of using the lowercase `l` and not forced to use capital `L` which requires the shift key. THE SHIFT KEY!!! (That would be awful.)

Comment: In defense of the `L`, it looks less like the number `1`.

Comment: @ gilcu2    val a:List[Long]=List(2513831384,2513831384) this doesn't work.  I am looking for a better way to write code piece then adding a 'l' at the end of each. I am somewhat new but I still think there shall be a better way

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't. That is the way to write a `Long`.

Answer (score 0):

```
val a:List[Long]=List(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference if you want to use numbers larger than an Int though.